# .NET Toolkit for Rally REST API Documentation deprecated?

Tags: c#, rally

I'm starting to work with Rally .NET API, in order to develop a plugin to import User Story into Enterprise Architect.

I have started by the examples in the following page: http://developer.help.rallydev.com/rest-api-net.

In the last one, for example, I got this errors:

```
//Create an item
DynamicJsonObject toCreate = new DynamicJsonObject();
toCreate["Name"] = "My Defect";
CreateResult createResult = restApi.Create("defect", toCreate);
```

> Error 1   No overload for method 'Create' takes 2 arguments

```
//Delete the item
OperationResult deleteResult = restApi.Delete(createResult.Reference);
```

> Error 2   No overload for method 'Delete' takes 1 arguments

But the documentation [here](https://docs.rallydev.com/restapinet/html/AllMembers_T_Rally_RestApi_RallyRestApi.htm) is different from the examples.

All in all, I would like to know any good sources of information to learn this Rally API and which is the correct implementation for the Create and Delete in the examples of the first page.

Thanks in advance,

Pedro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the confusion - with the latest release of the .NET REST DLL (version 1.0.15), both the Create and Delete methods changed slightly - they now require a Workspace Ref:

```
 String workspaceRef = "/workspace/12345678910";
 DynamicJsonObject toCreate = new DynamicJsonObject();
 toCreate["Name"] = "My Defect";
 CreateResult createResult = restApi.Create(workspaceRef, "defect", toCreate);
```

Delete should look like this:

```
 OperationResult deleteResult = restApi.Delete(workspaceRef, createResult.Reference);
```

Or this:

```
 myDefectObjectID = "12345678911";
 OperationResult deleteResult = restApi.Delete(workspaceRef, "Defect", myDefectObjectID);
```

We'll work to get the documentation updated as quickly as possible. Thanks for pointing this out!